# Jsf get ajax queue

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf

Is it possible to get the current jsf-ajax-queue in javascript?

I need to detect if there is currently any jsf-ajax request running.

The

```
jsf.ajax
```

object seems not to expose this information.

I dont want to add event listeners becuase this is only for selenium testing and not needed for production.

Comment: thought of this too, but i hoped to find a shorter solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *object seems not to expose this information.*

There's indeed no public API for that, as confirmed by [the `jsf.ajax` jsdoc](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/symbols/jsf.ajax.html).

Your best bet is to let Selenium programmatically register a global ajax listener beforehand via `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent` and `jsf.ajax.addOnError`. This way you can keep track of started, completed and errored requests yourself.